# Replace MPMoviePlayer notifications with JWPlayer notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, jwplayer

In iOS 9 `MPMoviePlayer` and all its components are deprecated. We are using notifications

1. `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification`
2. `MPMovieDurationAvailableNotification`
3. `MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification`
4. `MPMoviePlayerNowPlayingMovieDidChangeNotification`
5. `MPMovieNaturalSizeAvailableNotification`

We are migrating to `JWPlayer` because of the various benefits it provides. However, I am unable to find a concise list of notifications provided by `JWPlayer`.

Can anyone please help me with the same ?

Answer (score 1):

Use jwplayer delegate

http://sdk.jwplayer.com/ios/docs/reference/Protocols/JWPlayerDelegate.html

This is the concise list of all events provided by jwplayer. The only difference is that MPMoviePlayer gives it via NSNotification but JWPlayer gives it via delegate.